# AutoSize Text in Homescreen Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, textview, android-appwidget

Trying to get Text in a TextView to autosize to the size of the homescreen widget.  There are some very good classes that extend TextView, but I can't seem to get these to work with RemoteViews. (not sure if it's even possible).

With Resizable widgets, I find it bizzare there is no standard way to resize text to suit the size of the widget.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using StaticLayout / DynamicLayout ?

Comment: Are those even supported in homescreen widgets?

Comment: tried all sorts, not had any luck whatsoever with with.  Am I wasting my time, is this even possible?

Comment: Working on the same problem. Please tell if someone found a solution..